# Click Once Deployment has been modified by unknown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

Im trying to deploy my application in Visual Studio 2015 via ClickOnce. 
But I always need to empty my deployment folder before i deploy my app. 
Otherwise I get the error:

> The file setup.exe has been modified by (unknown)

Do you know what the error means? because i dont really get it.

Answer (score 0):

5 years ago... I hope you don't need this answer anymore...

I got the same error while transferring my My FTP server from IIS to Proftpd on a Linux server.

I think the problem is about FTP server settings. When you publish your ClickOnce program, Visual Studio will check the owner of existing files on FTP. If the file owner doesn't match your username logged on, it will report this error. You can check the username and group of files with Filezilla connecting to your server.

For Proftpd, you can turn off DirFakeUser setting in your configure file. By doing this, Proftpd will use your ftp username as file owner on your real filesystem. I wonder if it works for anonymous user. You can try it out if you are using anonymous user.